# Successive calls to Site.createPortalUser and Site.login fail with password invalid error

Tags: portal, force.com-sites, user, registration

Very strange case in which these calls:

```
id finalUserId = Site.createPortalUser(user,accountid,password,true);
if(finalUserId != null){    
    return Site.login(tu.email, password, 'PORTAL_Home?newuser=1');
}
```

Work perfectly in my dev environment but fail in production with an invalid password response, does anyone know in what situation this is able to fail?

We do have a lot of users and a very large role hierarchy possibly a race condition between user creation and registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through the debug files on user registration and a call to BMC it turns out that remedyforce has a default on option that automatically fires a password reset in a trigger for all new users, totally disregarding any options set through standard ui or the api.

Still quite miffed over this.

Answer (score 1):

I think your race theory is correct.

In the site class docs, they call CreatePortalUser, check to see that it returns the if if the new user, and then call login.

Besides avoiding the race conditions, you might also be abject to return the exception (if there is one) on user creation.  Typically for us that's been passwords that aren't allowed , or duplicate username / nickname issues.

Comment: Yes I am checking for the userid being returned and it's there quite happily, the user is created, it's just seemingly not respecting and setting the passed password parameter.

Comment: Can you post the actual code, then?  The snippet in the original post didn't have the id check and that makes it harder to be helpful.

Comment: Understood my view was that the id check was noise in the face of the user always being created and the standard functionality seemingly violating it's contracts.

Comment: What about: PageReference pr = site.login(...); system.debug(pr); return pr;  then you can at least see what's coming back in the debug log.

Comment: Another option would be to requery the user by that id, use it's username directly out of the DB.